# Pathfinder to Dungeon World Conversion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dungeon-world

For those that have attempted to do a Pathfinder (or D&D 3.5e) to Dungeon World conversion, how what aspects did you implement into the game's core design?  Do you believe that it truly added to the game, or did it throw the game off balance?  In terms of what I would add to Dungeon World, spells immediately come to mind.  However, I think I would try to balance the inclusion of new spells into the system by adding new boons for other classes to partake in as well.

Comment: You seem to be looking for discussion vs. framing a solvable problem. As such I'm voting to close since its not within our site guidelines then. IN general I would see PF and DW being completely incompatible short of a full rework of a pathfinder class into DW. Nothing from Pathfinder's core rules meshes with DW's resolution mechanics or its approach to narrative driven abilities.

Comment: Why don't you take this discussion to the chatroom?

Comment: A few iconic spells and classes are all I can really see being converted.  It's a cool idea, though, one I may pick up after I get some more DW experience.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convert, and why? (E.g., "I'm converting our PF campaign to DW, how do I convert X, Y, and Z?") It's unclear too whether you've already read DW's own material on conversion since you don't mention it.